# How to use beego's localize?

Tags: go, beego

I tried to use i18n but it can't work
i18n is below.
http://beego.me/docs/module/i18n.md

routers/init.go:

```
// Initialized language type list.
langs := strings.Split(models.Cfg.MustValue("lang", "types"), "|")
names := strings.Split(models.Cfg.MustValue("lang", "names"), "|")
langTypes = make([]*langType, 0, len(langs))
for i, v := range langs {
    langTypes = append(langTypes, &langType{
        Lang: v,
        Name: names[i],
    })
}

for _, lang := range langs {
    beego.Trace("Loading language: " + lang)
    if err := i18n.SetMessage(lang, "conf/"+"locale_"+lang+".ini"); err != nil {
        beego.Error("Fail to set message file: " + err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

routers/router.go

```
// Initialized language type list.
langs := strings.Split(models.Cfg.MustValue("lang", "types"), "|")
names := strings.Split(models.Cfg.MustValue("lang", "names"), "|")
langTypes = make([]*langType, 0, len(langs))
for i, v := range langs {
    langTypes = append(langTypes, &langType{
        Lang: v,
        Name: names[i],
    })
}

for _, lang := range langs {
    beego.Trace("Loading language: " + lang)
    if err := i18n.SetMessage(lang, "conf/"+"locale_"+lang+".ini"); err != nil {
        beego.Error("Fail to set message file: " + err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

I just copied and paste.

It is my full code.
https://github.com/shinriyo/sample_i18n

I'd like to know minimum code.

it is error

```
bee run
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [INFO] Uses 'sample_i18n' as 'appname'
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [INFO] Initializing watcher...
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [TRAC] Directory(/Users/shinriyo/src/sample_i18n/controllers)
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [TRAC] Directory(/Users/shinriyo/src/sample_i18n)
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [TRAC] Directory(/Users/shinriyo/src/sample_i18n/routers)
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [TRAC] Directory(/Users/shinriyo/src/sample_i18n/tests)
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [INFO] Start building...
main.go:4:2:
routers/init.go:2:1: expected 'package', found 'IDENT' langs
2015/05/24 17:48:56 [ERRO] ============== Build failed ===================
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was that:

1. Create translation files inside conf/ folder
2. Configure your translation list at conf/app.conf. My languages are en-US and pt-BR

   ```
   lang_types = "en-US|pt-BR"
   ```
3. Create file baseController.go inside controller/baseController/ folder
   with this code

   ```
   package controllers
   import (
         "github.com/astaxie/beego"
         "github.com/beego/i18n"
         "strings"
   )
   var langTypes []string // Languages that are supported.
   // baseController represents base router for all other app routers.
   // It implemented some methods for the same implementation;
   // thus, it will be embedded into other routers.
   type BaseController struct {
       beego.Controller // Embed struct that has stub implementation of the                     interface.
       i18n.Locale      // For i18n usage when process data and render template.
   }

   func init() {
       beego.AddFuncMap("i18n", i18n.Tr)

       // Initialize language type list.
       langTypes = strings.Split(beego.AppConfig.String("lang_types"), "|")

       // Load locale files according to language types.
       for _, lang := range langTypes {
           beego.Trace("Loading language: " + lang)
           if err := i18n.SetMessage(lang, "conf/"+"locale_"+lang+".ini"); err != nil {
               beego.Error("Fail to set message file:", err)
               return
           }
       }
   }

   // Prepare implemented Prepare() method for baseController.
   // It's used for language option check and setting.
   func (this *BaseController) Prepare() {
       // Reset language option.
       this.Lang = "" // This field is from i18n.Locale.
       beego.Trace("running prepare")
       // 1. Get language information from 'Accept-Language'.
       al := this.Ctx.Request.Header.Get("Accept-Language")
       if len(al) > 4 {
           al = al[:5] // Only compare first 5 letters.
           if i18n.IsExist(al) {
               this.Lang = al
           }
       }

       beego.Trace("Accept-Language is " + al)
       // 2. Default language is English.
       if len(this.Lang) == 0 {
           this.Lang = "en-US"
       }

       // Set template level language option.
       this.Data["Lang"] = this.Lang
   }
   ```
4. Use your custom BaseController in other controller.

   ```
   package controllers

   import (
       bc "github.com/myFirstApp/controllers/baseController"
   )

   type LoginController struct {
       bc.BaseController
   }

   func (c *LoginController) Get() {
       c.TplNames = "login.tpl"
   }
   ```
5. Use i18n in templates

   ```
   {{i18n .Lang "login.capitalized"}}
   ```

My locale_en-US.ini

```
    login = login
    [login]
    uppercase = LOGIN
    capitalized = Login
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/beego/i18n"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type BaseController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (b *BaseController) settingLocales() {
    // load locales with locale_LANG.ini files
    langs := "en-US|zh-CN"
    for _, lang := range strings.Split(langs, "|") {
        lang = strings.TrimSpace(lang)
        files := []string{"conf/" + "locale_" + lang + ".ini"}
        if fh, err := os.Open(files[0]); err == nil {
            fh.Close()
        } else {
            files = nil
        }
        if err := i18n.SetMessage(lang, "conf/"+"locale_"+lang+".ini", files...); err != nil {
            beego.Error("Fail to set message file: " + err.Error())
            os.Exit(2)
        }
    }
    Las := i18n.ListLangs()
    beego.Debug("langs:", Las)
}

func (b *BaseController) Get() {
    b.settingLocales()
    if i18n.IsExist("en-US") {
        b.Data["json"] = i18n.Tr("en-US", "hi")
    } else {
        b.Data["json"] = s
    }
    b.ServeJson()
}
```

create file locale_en-US.ini and locale_zh-CN.ini in conf/

in locale_en-US.ini like:

```
hi = hello
bye = goodbye
```